# In Star Trek, what is the Captain's Gig?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng

[This site](http://www.kitsune.addr.com/SF-Conversions/Rifts-Trek-Ships/Federation_USS_Galaxy_Cruiser.htm) says that a Galaxy-class Starship has a "*Captain's Gig*".

What is it and do we have any examples (from any episodes) of how it looks or works?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The "Gig" is in fact the small vessel (known as the "[Captain's yacht](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Captain%27s_yacht)") docked underneath the ship's saucer section on the Enterprises D and E.

[image]

The one on the Enterprise-D (The '[Calypso](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Calypso)') was never used or even referred to in the TV show, with descriptions existing solely in the various technical manuals and trading cards:

[image]

There's a brief overview in the [TNG Technical Manual](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Star_Trek:_The_Next_Generation_Technical_Manual):

> *This is one of those nifty things that we may never get to see on the
> show. We did briefly flirt with the idea of actually using the
> captain's yacht in Samaritan Snare, but it was decided to use an
> "executive shuttlecraft" instead. Patrick Stewart informs us that the
> yacht is named Calypso, after Jacques Cousteau's ship. Visual effects
> coordinator (and Navy veteran) **Ron B. Moore points out that naval
> tradition would probably insist the craft be called the Captain's Gig.***

---

The one on the Enterprise-E (the '[Cousteau](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Cousteau_(yacht))') was used briefly in the film Star Trek : Insurrection. You can see it in the film clip below and the original concept art [here](https://johneaves.wordpress.com/2010/11/12/the-cousteau-picards-yacht-part-1/)

Comment: Similar to the Enterprise D, both Voyager and Equinox had one as well that was never used or referenced on screen http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Captain%27s_yacht

Comment: @geewhiz - Yes, although the Voyager one was listed in the technical manual as "awaiting fitting out" which explains why it wasn't used in a couple of episodes where it would have been useful, either as a weapon or as a lifeboat.

Comment: Didn't the "captain's yacht" also get featured in Star Trek : Nemesis - when they went on that scavenger hunt for Data's "brother" "B4"?

Comment: @AnthonyX - That was the [Argo](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Argo_(shuttlecraft)), described as a "[Heavy Transport Shuttle](https://johneaves.wordpress.com/2009/03/23/nemesis-and-the-argo/)" by its creator, John Eaves

Answer (score 2):

It seems to be a [Captain's Yacht](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Captain%27s_yacht)..

> The captain's yacht was a large shuttle built into the design of several Federation starship designs including the Galaxy-class and Sovereign-class. It was docked to the underside of the saucer section. Although it was built mainly for diplomatic missions it was also combat capable.
>
> ..
>
> Ronald B. Moore notes in the Star Trek: The Next Generation Technical Manual that naval tradition would insist on calling such a craft the *Captain's gig* rather than the *Captain's yacht.*

[image]

Comment: See here for [the historical antecedent of the Captain's Gig](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Captain%27s_gig).